# FlatList Conditional Styling not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to do some conditional styling on the flatlist, but it turns out that it is not fully functional. I don't know what am I missing here, help would be appreciated.

below is the code, where the last condition is working item.status == 5

```
<Text
  style={[
    item.status == 1 ? styles.Approved : styles.orderStatusText,
    item.status == 2 ? styles.Sold : styles.orderStatusText,
    item.status == 3 ? styles.UnderReview : styles.orderStatusText,
    item.status == 4 ? styles.Inactive : styles.orderStatusText,
    item.status == 5 ? styles.Deleted : styles.orderStatusText
  ]}
>
  {item.status}
</Text>
```

API code

```
UserProducts() {
  fetch(`http://`, {
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(resp => {
      this.setState({
        UserProducts: resp
      });
      console.log("Success", this.state.LastProduct);
      console.log("Test", seller_id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Api call error1");
    });
}
```

example of one of the style:

```
  Deleted: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: Theme.regularFont,
    color: 'red', 
    paddingLeft: 8,
    fontWeight: '400'
},
```

Comment: can you share complete code because what is in item.status and what is your requirement?

Comment: item.status is coming from API response, I have have to apply style according to the status codes. @VahidAkhtar

Comment: i know but post complete code because it's array or what?

Comment: You'd be better off moving this out into a switch case. And when you say it's "not fully functional", what specifically do you mean? And have you logged to make sure `item.status` is what you think it is?

Comment: @Jayce444 Not fully functional because (item.status) == 5) is working according to the style in the condition

Comment: @VahidAkhtar updated, please check and let me know if you want to know more. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `===` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <Text 
     style={[styles.orderStatusText]}>
     {(item.status === 1) ? <Text style={styles.Approved}>Approved</Text> : null}
     {(item.status === 2) ? <Text style={styles.Sold}>Sold</Text> : null}
     {(item.status === 3) ? <Text style={styles.UnderReview}>Under Review</Text> : null}
     {(item.status === 4) ? <Text style={styles.Inactive}>Inactive</Text> : null}
     {(item.status === 5) ? <Text style={styles.Deleted}>Deleted</Text> : null}
</Text>
```

I happened to think and did this, worked super well.